# Unexpected command line syntax error in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

I have been trying to run some node js files. I have checked the files and they seem to have no syntax errors whatsoever. However, upon running the file on the node js command line i get this error

```
node first.js
 ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Lately, I have also been unable to run my apache web server from XAMPP. Could this be a port assignee error. Or is it something else. *I have also, checked the directory of the file and it checks out*

Some help would be greatly appreciate

Comment: Does your "JavaScript" source file literally say `node first.js`?

Comment: No i simply ran `node first.js` on my node.js command line

Comment: You need to run the command `node first.js` as a command from the *system* command line. Once you start Node, you're in the Node repl and it expects you to type JavaScript statements.

Comment: So do I first write node. Then when this `>` appears I then type `node first.js`.

Comment: No, you write `node first.js` from the system command line.

Comment: Check your PATH variables (System Properties > Advanced > Environment Variables)

Comment: @Pointy thank you very much it worked do you want to post it as an answer to make it official.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're inside node's CLI, you can run JS or rather node supported instructions. Unfortunately, there is no global variable or keyword with name "node". If you want to run "first.js", you'll have to come out from node's cli and then run the command.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't run file with `node first.js` inside file js

- node is `undefined`
- That is't right syntax

If you want run `first.js` file, you can include it with `require`

```
let first = require('first);
```

but this way run it once (first time call it), you can use method inside `first.js` with `export`(or `module.exports`) of `first.js`.

But you just want call and run `first.js`, you can use [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html).